# create_time in sys.dm_xe_sessions is in the future

Tags: sql-server-2014, extended-events, time

I have run the following query which shows the running XE sessions on the server:

```
SELECT  name,
        create_time
FROM    sys.dm_xe_sessions
```

and I get the results

```
+-------------------------------+-------------------------+
|             name              |       create_time       |
+-------------------------------+-------------------------+
| hkenginexesession             | 2020-01-04 06:39:14.240 |
| system_health                 | 2020-01-04 06:39:14.313 |
| Deadlocks                     | 2020-01-04 06:39:14.483 |
| sp_server_diagnostics session | 2020-01-04 06:39:14.583 |
| Blocked Processes             | 2019-11-20 14:27:49.593 |
+-------------------------------+-------------------------+
```

Note that the first four sessions, 3 of which are system, 1 of which is user created (Deadlocks) have a `create_time` in the future.

I can verify the system time is correct doing a simple

`SELECT GETDATE()`

The `Blocked Processes` xe session has been created since the last server restart (which was `2019-11-15 13:36:35.287`)

What could have caused this?

SQL Server Version is

`Microsoft SQL Server 2014 (SP3-CU4) (KB4500181) - 12.0.6329.1 (X64)   Jul 20 2019 21:42:29   Copyright (c) Microsoft Corporation  Enterprise Edition (64-bit) on Windows NT 6.3 <X64> (Build 9600: ) (Hypervisor)`

Comment: Could it be that until server last restart system clock was wrong on this server? You can examin previous errorlog to check if the dates were correct there.

Comment: And please update your question with the full @@version, if it is RTM there is nothing to be surprising

Comment: The current SQL Server log starts at 15/11/2019 up to the present day. there are no 2020 entries

Comment: I asked about the **previuos** errorlog

Comment: What time is reported by `SELECT sqlserver_start_time FROM sys.dm_os_sys_info;`?

Comment: @sepupic the previous log is sequenced as it should be and it ends at 15/11/2016

Comment: @DanGuzman, the output is `2019-11-15 13:36:14.933`

Comment: @SEarle1986 did you ever figure this out? Having this issue on a SQL Server 2014 SP3 box ((SP3-CU4-GDR) (KB4583462)) and can't explain it either.

Comment: @mbourgon no I don't believe I did, it was a minor issue that I raised here out of curiosity, I can't recall seeing it again since, though the server this will have been on was upgraded to SQL Server 2016 around 6 months ago

Answer (score 2):

This is actually a bug - that has been corrected as of SQL Server 2022 CU4 (16.0.4035.4) - and possibly with lower versions of SQL Server 2022.

The problem also does not, obviously, manifest with Azure SQL Database (via `sys.dm_xe_database_sessions`) either.

I can easily repro this issue via the following query:

```sql
SELECT 
    [name], 
    [create_time], 
    GETUTCDATE() [now] 
FROM 
    sys.[dm_xe_sessions];
```

With results similar to the following:
[image]

The above can be reproduced on:

- SQL Server 2014
- SQL Server 2016
- SQL Server 2017
- SQL Server 2019 (CU20)

And the timestamp issues applies equally against internal (system created) sessions vs user-defined sessions as well.

The problem does NOT exist against SQL Server 2022 instances (or as mentioned above, Azure).